# Posting file through angular http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm using angularjs and I'm trying to upload a picture to a django backend server along with other data in the request body.

I keep getting an error from the server telling me that the picture I sent was not a file. (Assume that the backend has no problems)

I've tried using ng-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to get the file and then send it through angular itself. (Note: I need to send other data along with the picture) so I want to store the file in a variable and pass it in the request body like so:

```
<form name="form">
<div class="button" ngf-select ng-model="file" name="file" ngf-resize="{width: 100, height: 100}">Select</div>
<button type="submit" ng-click="submit()">submit</button>
</form>
```

since the file is stored in $scope.file, I try to use it in the http request:

```
$http({
          'method': "PUT",
          'url': "api/candidate-profiles/" + id,
          'data':data
})
```

where data is:

```
{"id": $scope.id,
"name": $scope.name,
"avatar":$scope.file}
```

I get a validation error from the backend specifiying that the avatar is not a file. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
            <form  name="userForm"  class="well form-search"   >

                <input type="text" ng-model="name" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Name" required >
                <input type="email" ng-model="email" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Email" required >
                <input type="text" ng-model="message" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Message" required >
                <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="formsubmit(userForm.$valid)"  ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit </button>

            </form>
            <pre ng-model="result">
                {{result}}
            </pre>
        </div>
```

**jsfile**

```
var app = angular.module('formExample', []);

app.controller("formCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'submit.php';

        $scope.formsubmit = function(isValid) {


            if (isValid) {


                $http.post($scope.url, {"name": $scope.name, "email": $scope.email, "message": $scope.message}).
                        success(function(data, status) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.status = status;
                            $scope.data = data;
                            $scope.result = data; // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
                        })
            }else{

                  alert('Form is not valid');
            }


        } }]);
```

[Code Download](http://shabeebk.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/form_submit.zip)

[demo click](http://shabeebk.com/blog/simple-form-submit-in-angularjs-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the documentation, and see some samples like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/)

```js
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'Upload', '$timeout', function ($scope, Upload, $timeout) {
    $scope.uploadPic = function(file) {
    file.upload = Upload.upload({
        url: 'https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload',
        data: {username: $scope.username, file: file},
    });

    file.upload.then(function (response) {
        $timeout(function () {
            file.result = response.data;
        });
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.status > 0)
          $scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
    }, function (evt) {
        // Math.min is to fix IE which reports 200% sometimes
        file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
    });
    }
}]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/